# joining custom table with EAV table

Tags: magento-1.8

I am New to the Magento, I am using the Magento 1.8.
I am stucked while prepare collection function in custom admin module while adding values to the grid.

I have custom table called **foundation [not a EAV table]** their are 3 fields

**|foundation_id | store_id | member_email|**
I want to join it with inbuilt EAV table **core_store_group**

My prepareCollection Function is as follows

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('core/store_group')->getCollection()
->addFilter('website_id',2)
->addFilter('root_category_id',3);
$collection->getSelect()->join(Mage::getConfig()
->getTablePrefix().'foundation', 'core_store_group.group_id ='.Mage::getConfig()
->getTablePrefix().'foundation.store_id',array('member_email'));
$this->setCollection($collection);
parent::_prepareCollection();
return $this;
```

I am getting the following Error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'core_store_group.group_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: I think your first argument to join need to be a table alias for the foundation table: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `core_store_group` table is not EAV.
But that's not important
Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('core/store_group')->getCollection()
    ->addFilter('website_id',2)
    ->addFilter('root_category_id',3);
$collection->getSelect()->join(
            array('foundation' => $collection->getTable('[module]/foundation')),
            'main_table.group_id = foundation.store_id',
            array('member_email')
);
$this->setCollection($collection);
parent::_prepareCollection();
return $this;
```

Just replace `[module]` with your modulename in lowercase.

Comment: Hi Marius, If I wanted to display count(member_email) then, how I need to change above code..

Comment: Hi Marius, You code working fine but I am getting error when another store_id is added to my custom table foundation. store_id in foundation table is reference so. that show the which email id belongs to which store and one store can have more than one email id. I am getting this error **Item (Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group) with the same id "2" already exist**  when I add another record with same store_id

Comment: @Charlie. Magento collections do now support items with the same id. That's why you get the error. Maybe you should try to make the collection the other way around. I mean start with your entity mapped to `[module]/foundation` table and join with the store group table.